# Spacing around \tilde{=}

Tags: math-mode, spacing, stacking-symbols, relation-symbols, tilde

How can I get proper spacing when using `tilde` over operator symbols?

```
\begin{align*}
x &= y\\
x &\tilde{=} b
\end{align*}
```

Yields:

[image]

But I would like the tilde version to have the same kind of spacing as normal equality

Comment: Why don't you use `\simeq` or `\cong` instead?

Answer (score 10):

You can make arbitrary symbol a relation by wrapping it into `\mathrel{}`. For example: `\mathrel{\tilde{=}}` will use the correct spaces around it. There are other ways: `\stackrel{}{}` (as Herbert noted), or use of a predefined symbol like `\cong`. They all have different looks. Chose what you prefer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\teq{\mathrel{\tilde{=}}}
\newcommand\seq{\stackrel{\sim}{=}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
x &= y\\
x &\teq b\\
x &\seq b\\
x &\cong b\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\begin{align*}
x &= y\\
x &\stackrel{\sim}{=} b
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here there is another minimal example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x &= y\\
x &\overset{\sim}{=} b
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
x &= y\\
x &\overset{\thicksim}{=} b
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```